# SQL JOINING ISSUE

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g

I have two different tables but both table may or may not have same records. i need to join these tables and get all the different records for both the tables

for example

```
CREATE TABLE sql_test_a 
( 
    ID         VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    LAST_NAME  VARCHAR2(200 BYTE) 
); 

CREATE TABLE sql_test_b 
( 
    ID         VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    LAST_NAME  VARCHAR2(200 BYTE) 
); 

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES ('1', 'John', 'Snow'); 

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES ('2', 'Mike', 'Tyson'); 

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES ('3', 'Bill', 'Keaton'); 

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES ('4', 'Greg', 'Mercury'); 

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES ('5', 'Steve', 'Jobs'); 

INSERT INTO sql_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES ('6', 'Stsdsdve', 'Josdsbs');

INSERT INTO sql_test_b (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES ('1', 'John', 'Snow'); 

INSERT INTO sql_test_b (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES ('2', 'Mike', 'Tyson'); 

INSERT INTO sql_test_b (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES ('3', 'Bill', 'Keaton'); 

INSERT INTO sql_test_b (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES ('4', 'Greg', 'Mercury'); 

INSERT INTO sql_test_b (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES ('5', 'Steve', 'Jobs'); 

INSERT INTO sql_test_b (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES ('7', 'Johhny', 'Depp');

INSERT INTO sql_test_b (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES ('8', 'Johhnaaaay', 'Deaaap');
```

these are the tables and the records in the tables

and the excepted output should be

```
ID  FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME
1   John        Snow
2   Mike        Tyson
3   Bill        Keaton
4   Greg        Mercury
5   Steve       Jobs
6   Stsdsdve    Josdsbs
7   Johhny      Depp
8   Johhnaaaay  Deaaap
```

i tried different join like left outer join, full outer join etc

```
SELECT a.ID,a.FIRST_NAME,a.LAST_NAME
  FROM sql_test_a a left outer join sql_test_b b on a.ID=b.ID 
  and a.FIRST_NAME=b.FIRST_NAME 
  and a.LAST_NAME=b.LAST_NAME
```

this query wont give the exact output

please help

Comment: You would be better using a union for that. Left or Right joins only return all records in one or other side (left or right), never in both. A Union would give you a deduplicated list of result.

Comment: can you just help me with the query

Comment: Do you use MySQL, MS SQL Server or another tool?

Comment: im using oracle 11g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UNION` operator returns unique rows of combined queries. So, just use

```
SELECT * FROM sql_test_a UNION SELECT * FROM sql_test_b
```

To filter the result using `WHERE` clause you could use subquery. For example

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM sql_test_a UNION SELECT * FROM sql_test_b)
WHERE ID > 3
```

See also [live fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/264cd/9).

Comment: thanks very much. it works. i have a doubt how to filter this data using where clause

Comment: @angel, just use the statement in subquery. The answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `union` you can get the list you need (note that `union all` could give you duplicate rows depending on your data):

```
select a.id as id, a.first_name as first_name, a.last_name as last_name
from sql_test_a a

union

select b.id as id, b.first_name as first_name, b.last_name as last_name
from sql_test_b b
```

Using a join is discouraged in this case since it will give you a table with more than three columns, joined on (at least) one of them.

**EDIT**

You mention you're using oracle. To filter this, you can do several things, among which, one is wrap the query in a temporary table

```
with tmp as (

    select a.id as id, a.first_name as first_name, a.last_name as last_name
    from sql_test_a a

    union

    select b.id as id, b.first_name as first_name, b.last_name as last_name
    from sql_test_b b
)

select tmp.id, tmp.first_name, tmp.last_name
from tmp
where 
    tmp.first_name like '%whatever%';
```

Comment: thanks very much. it works. i have a doubt how to filter this data using where clause

Comment: @angel I updated the answer. If you feel it was sufficient, please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

```
(   SELECT * FROM sql_test_a 
MINUS
SELECT * FROM sql_test_b)  UNION ALL(   SELECT * FROM sql_test_b
MINUS
SELECT * FROM sql_test_a )
```

Comment: Changed from EXCEPT to MINUS .Please try now.EXCEPT is for SQL Server.

Comment: Why do you complicate simple solution?

Comment: @Alexander Can you please suggest a more simpler way.

Comment: Yes. The [`UNION`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) operator combines queries results and removes duplicated rows :)

Comment: The `SELECT * FROM sql_test_a UNION SELECT * FROM sql_test_b` solves the question. It's simple way.

Comment: @Alexander   ok.got it .Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try this Please

(   SELECT * FROM sql_test_1
)  UNION ALL(   SELECT * FROM sql_test_b
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM sql_test_1 )